# The form of the angle between two curves on surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, angle

**Problem**: Given the surface $\overrightarrow{r}_{uv}=(u \cos v, u \sin v, u^2)$. Find the angle of two curves $v=u+1$, $v=3-u$.

**Approach** Here is what I've done so far:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\overrightarrow{r_{u}^{\prime}}=(\cos v, \sin v, 2 u) \\
\overrightarrow{r_{v}^{\prime}}=(-u \sin v, u \cos v, 0)
\end{gathered}
$$
Parametrized two curves $\rho_{1}: v=u+1$ và $\rho_{2}: v=3-u$
$$
\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}}:\left\{\begin{array}{c}
u_{1}(t)=t \\
v_{1}(t)=t+1
\end{array} \text { and } \overrightarrow{\rho_{2}}:\left\{\begin{array}{c}
u_{2}(s)=s \\
v_{2}(s)=3-s
\end{array} .\right.\right.
$$
The derivatives are
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{\begin{array} { l } 
{ u _ { 1 } ^ { \prime } ( t ) = 1 } \\
{ v _ { 1 } ^ { \prime } ( t ) = 1 }
\end{array} \text { and } \left\{\begin{array}{c}
u_{2}^{\prime}(s)=1 \\
v_{2}^{\prime}(s)=-1
\end{array} .\right.\right.
\end{aligned}
$$
The intersection of two curves on $(S)$ is $\rho_{1}(1)=\rho_{2}(1)$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}(1)=u_{1}^{\prime}(1) \cdot \overrightarrow{r_{u}^{\prime}}+v_{1}^{\prime}(1) \cdot \overrightarrow{r_{v}^{\prime}}=(\cos v-u \sin v, \sin v+u \cos v, 2 u) \\
&\overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}(1)=u_{2}^{\prime}(1) \cdot \overrightarrow{r_{u}^{\prime}}+v_{2}^{\prime}(1) \cdot \overrightarrow{r_{v}^{\prime}}=(\cos v+u \sin v, \sin v-u \cos v, 2 u).
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies
$$
 \left\langle \overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}(1), \overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}(1)\right\rangle=\cos ^{2} v-u^{2} \sin ^{2} v+\sin ^{2} v-u^{2} \cos ^{2} v+4 u^{2}=3 u^{2}+1
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\left\|\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}(1)\right\|&=\sqrt{\cos ^{2} v+u^{2} \sin ^{2} v-2 u \cos v \sin v+\sin ^{2} v+u^{2} \cos ^{2} v+2 u \sin v \cos v+4 u^{2}} \\
&=\sqrt{5 u^{2}+1}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left\|\overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}(1)\right\|&=\sqrt{\cos ^{2} v+u^{2} \sin ^{2} v+2 u \cos v \sin v+\sin ^{2} v+u^{2} \cos ^{2} v-2 u \sin v \cos v+4 u^{2}} \\
&=\sqrt{5 u^{2}+1}
\end{align}
$$
We have
$$
\cos (\alpha)=\frac{\left\langle\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}\left(t_{0}\right), \overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}\left(t_{0}\right)\right\rangle}{\left\|\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}\left(t_{0}\right)\right\| \cdot\left\|\overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}\left(t_{0}\right)\right\|}=\frac{3u^2 +1 }{5u^2 +1}
$$

**Question:** So the angle between two curves is a function as $u$. Is this possible? Or should I replace $u$ with another value?

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Actually the curves are given by $(u\cos(u+1),u\sin(u+1),u^2)$ and $(u\cos(3-u),u\sin(3-u),u^2)$.  They intersect if $u+1=3-u+2k\pi$ and $u+1=\pi-(3-u)+2k\pi$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe thank you for pointing out my mistake. Even so, I think the angle is still depended on $u$ because $\overrightarrow{r_{u}^{\prime}}$ and $\overrightarrow{r_{v}^{\prime}}$ depend on $u$ and it leads to the dependence on $u$ of $\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}^{\prime}}$,  $\overrightarrow{\rho_{2}^{\prime}}$